# Executing module in another Excel workbook, using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to make this work forever.
I want to execute a module in another workbook from the current workbook, wbCntl.
The exactcode works in one application but not in another.

sSignalInProcess and wbSignalInProcess are defined correctly.  The idea is to either open or create the sSignalInProcess file on the first pass, then skip that code on subsequent running of its code.

Here's my code:

```
Sub GetSignalFile()
    'Open workbook if signal file is open
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbSignalInProcess = Workbooks(sSignalInProcess)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        'Open existing signal workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wbSignalInProcess = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath & sSignalInProcess)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            'Copy template signal workbook to a new workbook file for new signal
            FileCopy (sStdSignal), (sFilePath & sSignalInProcess)
            wbSignalInProcess.Save
            'Open new signal workbook
            Set wbSignalInProcess = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath & sSignalInProcess)
        End If
    End If
    Err.Clear
    Application.Run (wbSignalInProcess.Name & "!MainIntuitor")
    wbCntl.Activate
End Sub
```

The line

```
 Application.Run (wbSignalInProcess.Name & "!MainIntuitor")
```

is skipped and not executed without an error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Grant

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add

```
 On Error Goto 0
```

before the critical line. Perhaps you will get a more helpful error message then. By the way, the second

```
 On Error Resume Next
```

in your code is not necessary - once you activated "`Resume Next`", it keeps beeing activated until you leave your Sub or deactivate it with `On Error Goto 0`.